# monodroid Steema.TeeChart.TChart : how to disable user interaction

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, teechart

can any one please tell me how to disable user interaction in TChart Control.

i know how to do this in monotouch linechart.UserInteractionEnabled = false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this:

```
  tChart1.Zoom.Style = Steema.TeeChart.ZoomStyles.Classic;
  tChart1.Zoom.Allow = false;
  tChart1.Panning.Allow = ScrollModes.None;
```

*ZoomStyles.Classic* is still not fully implemented. Hence setting *Zoom.Allow* and *Panning.Allow* is not necessary for now but it will once full functionality is completed.

**UPDATE:** Full *ZoomStyles.Classic* functionality is implemented in the [4.14.6.25 version published on 26th June 2014](http://www.steema.com/entry/217/TeeChart_for_Xamarin.Android_4.14.6.25_maintenance_release_available).

If disabling zoom and scroll/panning is not you meant by user interaction please let me know.

Comment: @user2330792 you're very welcome. Please vote and accept my reply if you thing it's what you were looking for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2330792 a new version was published yesterday implementing that: http://www.steema.com/entry/217/TeeChart_for_Xamarin.Android_4.14.6.25_maintenance_release_available

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the created chart to be viewed but not manipulated by user controls why not just disable it?

```
tChart1.Enabled = false;
```